# Выделяется ли запятыми оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

"Люблю походы и(,) за неимением возможности в них ходить(,) описываю в своей книге". Нужны ли тут запятые?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструкции с простыми или составными предлогами *благодаря, ввиду, вследствие, по причине, наподобие, подобно, при условии, при наличии, при, вопреки, **за неимением,** согласно, с согласия, во избежание* и др обычно не обособляются, но в художественной речи в зависимости от степени распространенности оборота, его смысловой близости к основной части предложения занимаемого им места по отношению к сказуемому, наличия добавочных обстоятельственных значений, стилистических задач и т.п. могут обособляться (Розенталь).

В вашем случае я бы все же поставила запятые, поскольку обстоятельственная конструкция находится посреди предложения и, как мне кажется, имеет дополнительное обстоятельственное значение (причинное + уступительное).

Answer (score 2):

Обороты, начинающиеся с "ввиду", "за отсутствием", "по причине", "согласно", "за неимением" и т.п., обособляются факультативно, то бишь всё зависит от желания автора. Хотите - выделяйте запятыми, не хотите - не выделяйте. Лично я такие конструкции обычно обособляю, так как в устной речи перед этими оборотами я делаю паузы.

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение с производным предлогом обособляется, если оно:
1) распространено (то есть имеет в составе зависимые слова);
2) стоит перед сказуемым;
3) имеет добавочное причинное или уступительное значение.

Все три признака налицо. Значит, запятые нужны.